# Prove that $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ can be expressed in terms of the Laplacian

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, vector-fields

How does one go about proving that the dot product of the gradient functions $\nabla{u} \cdot \nabla{v}$, where $u$ and $v$ are both scalar functions is equal to : $\frac{1}{2}[ \nabla^{2}{(uv)} - u\nabla^{2}{v} -  v\nabla^{2}{u}] $.

I tried indexing this using Kronecker Delta however I couldn't arrive at a solution. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Einstein notation (also called summation notation) to prove this. I would write:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2 (uv) & = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \left( \frac{\partial (uv)}{\partial x_i}\right) \\
 & = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \left( u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} + v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right) \\
 & = 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} + u \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_i \partial x_i} + v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_i}
\end{aligned}
$$

Since:
$$
u \nabla^2 v = u \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_i \partial x_i}
$$
and
$$
v \nabla^2 u = v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_i}
$$

We have shown that:

$$
\frac{1}{2} \left[ \nabla^2 (uv) - u \nabla^2v - v\nabla^2u \right] = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} = \nabla u \cdot \nabla v
$$

Comment: Yep, thanks, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer if it's what you were looking for.